# NULL being returned on a Cumulative Sum SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table of individual sales, for which I would like to summarise into two columns, with a monthly total in one and a cumulative sum in another.

```
select Year, Month, 'Acquisition Income' = SUM(PAYMENTAMOUNT), 
        'Acquisition Cumulative' = (select SUM(PAYMENTAMOUNT)
                                        from #CampaignPayments b
                                        where (a.Year >= b.Year and a.Month >= b.Month)
                                        or (a.Year > b.Year) ) 
into #CampaignTotals
from #CampaignPayments a
group by YEAR, MONTH
order by YEAR asc, MONTH asc
```

However, I am running into some trouble, where some months, there were no payments, thus my 'Acquisition Income' for that month is `NULL`.

```
Year    Month   Acquisition Income  Acquisition Cumulative
2013    5       121782               121782
2013    6       25959.2              147741.2
2013    7       2875                 150616.2
2013    8       1995                 152611.2
2013    9       625                  153236.2
2013    10      590                  153826.2
2013    11      935                  154761.2
2013    12      550                  155311.2
2014    1       777                  156088.2
2014    2       210                  156298.2
2014    3       75                   156373.2
2014    4       520                  156893.2
2014    5       150                  157043.2
2014    6       340                  157383.2
2014    7       NULL                 NULL
2014    8       30                   157413.2
```

How do I

(a): Return `0` rather than `NULL` in the 'Acquisition Income' column ( I have tried `coalesce(SUM(paymentamount),0)` as well as `isnull`, but neither work.)

(b): Continue to calculate the 'Acquisition Cumulative' column, even when no payments were made in that month? (i.e. the sum is the same as the previous month)

To be honest, I am not totally understanding how the cumulative sum works - to me it seems like as each row is returned, it should sum all payments that meet the criteria in the where/or clause, so I am not sure why having no payments in that month would affect the sum for the previous months?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Perhaps `SUM(ISNULL(PAYMENTAMOUNT, 0))` could help?

Comment: Not that it will make any difference to your problem but I think the first condition would be better stated as `a.Year = b.Year and a.Month >= b.Month`. In any case, coalescing the sum won't help because any nulls will cause you to lose information for the whole month. I think you'd be better off with something like summing the coalesced values: `sum(coalesce(paymentamount,0))`.

Comment: @paxdiablo - didn't work. I didn't think it would. I'm thinking there is a problem with that month not having any payments.

Comment: @IvanSivak - Unfortunately doesn't work either...

Comment: If there were no payments for that month, surely the `select` would not return a row at all rather than return a row with null?

Comment: It is returning a row with NULL actually

Comment: Do you have months where there is a row with `NULL` instead of `0`?

Comment: What is the type of `PAYMENTAMOUNT`? It would help if you added the `CREATE TABLE` script in the question. Even better if you included the rows for the month that causes the issue.

Comment: paymentamount type is money. And yes to your first question.

Comment: If you have nulls, the suggestion above to use `SUM(ISNULL(PAYMENTAMOUNT, 0))` (in both expressions) should have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here you go

SELECT  [Year], 
       [Month],  
       [Acquisition Income], 
       SUM([Acquisition Income]) OVER( ORDER BY [Year], [Month]
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS [Acquisition Cumulative]
INTO #CampaignTotals
FROM
    (

    SELECT Year, Month, ISNULL(SUM(PAYMENTAMOUNT), 0) AS 'Acquisition Income'          
    FROM #CampaignPayments a
    GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH    
    ) AS OuterSet
```

Comment: You don't need a subquery but I think this is correct (assuming they use a not too old version of SQL-Server).

Comment: I wasn't using the sub query, it was a derived table expression :)

Comment: Yes, I meant the derived table.